# What are some good plant suggestions for a cool climate in an apartment?

Tags: houseplants, plant-recommendations, flowers

I'm staying in an apartment which has no balcony (it's a single bedroom house). I want some flowers/houseplants which do not require much sunlight or space. Can some one suggest any plants? The temperature is fairly cool.

Updated: Can I get plants suggestions which is suitable for Indian climate where i don't get few plants which are mentioned in this **[link](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/low-maintenance-plant-choices-for-apartment-indoor-living)**

Comment: Do you have a problem with the (many and variable) plants recommended in those answers?

Comment: no, I don't know whether i can get these plants in India, Let me try these plants were available here or not.. Thanks..

Comment: I can go for Pothos (Epipremnum aureum). I know it is available..

Comment: Are you satisfied with that?

Comment: Yes :-) this is one option, I will be happy if i can get any flower plant too

Comment: Can you get a Spathiphyllum?

Comment: I don't have idea....I didn't saw this plant  :(

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a list of some very easy houseplants for your conditions. I will not be able to find sources for you, you'll have to work that out yourself. :)

- [***Sansevieria sp.*, or snake plant.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sansevieria) This plant requires little soil, water, fertilizer, and light, and can take hot dry temps. One of the easiest plants for beginners.
- [***Chlorophytum comosum*, or Spider plant.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophytum_comosum) Very low care plant. I've seen them survive in the same pot without fertilizer for over 15 years.
- [***Aglaonema sp.*, or Chinese evergreen.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglaonema) This will grow in very low light conditions.
- [***Epipremnum aureum*, or Golden Pothos**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum) My first plant when I was a kid. Very easy to grow. Takes a very low light level, but in that condition, don't water too much.
- [***Spathiphyllum sp.*, or Peace Lily.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathiphyllum) This one likes some humidity, and moist soil, but is easy to grow.
- [***Dracaena braunii*, or Lucky Bamboo.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_braunii) This is a fun plant to grow and is fairly low care.