Does anybody know some low-maintenance indoor plants for summer?
I've been planning to decorate my home with some indoor plants that are easy to grow. And have found many common plants but I am not sure if they'll thrive in Summer or not. I tried checking their care routine and couldn't find anything helpful. Please suggest some plants. The average temperature in my region is 41℃ (106℉) during the day and 29℃ (84℉) during the night. I plan to place the plants in front of my north-facing window. So far I haven't tried any indoor plants and if required I can place my outdoors.

Define “summer” please? This can mean very different things in different parts of the world. And for any plant choice, light levels are at least equally important as temperature and humidity. Without more details, this is opinion-based at best, which makes the question off topic. We can of course reopen after a meaningful edit.

Without further detail, silk or plastic or otherwise artifical for "decorating" with unknown levels of care. Though there are some fairly tough customers that will survive casual care by the inexperienced if given some light and water.

@App-Plantora Here is another question that might interest you: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-are-some-low-maintenance-plant-choices-for-apartment-indoor-living?rq=1

What indoor plants have you tried that worked for you?  Where do windows face (north, south, east, west)?  Are they unobstructed by buildings or trees?  Do you intend to put the interior plants outside for the summer?

Summer is generally when most houseplants grow the best. I don't think you have much to worry about there.
However, I would recommend Chlorophytum comosum. They're pretty easy to care for and are rewarding plants. You do have to rotate them, though.

Thank you for the suggestion. I'll definitely check it out.
